# Calculate Average, Mean, Max and Min Temperature & Humidity from a text file in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to get the average, mean, max and min temperature and humidity form a text file. This text file is capturing everyday data of temp & Humidity.
I am facing the problem with the formats of the data which are as follows:

```
2017-05-02 17:31:13 24.00,49.00
2017-05-02 17:32:13 24.00,49.00
2017-05-02 17:33:13 24.00,49.00  
2017-05-02 17:34:14 24.00,49.00  
2017-05-02 17:35:14 24.00,49.00 
2017-05-02 17:36:14 24.00,49.00 
2017-05-02 17:37:14 24.00,49.00  
2017-05-02 17:38:14 24.00,49.00
```

here, I am not able to split the columns properly as there are many spliters.
I can calculate average and all, but first the program should read the column of temp & humidity.

Data Description:
1st column: Date
2nd column: time
3rd column: Temp
4th column: Humidity

Can someone please help me to read the both temp and humidity properly, so that I can calculate average and all.

Comment: show us what you have tried so far?

Comment: one simple idea is to use the "," to locate your two values - 5 characters before and 5 after. At least that is what I would do - in excel.

Comment: replace the comma with a whitespace, then split the line at the whitespaces. There are tons of receipies: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3277503/how-do-i-read-a-file-line-by-line-into-a-list

Comment: Furthermore, I would try to change the data logger so that it does not include this stupid comma. I would use pandas to analyse the data (if the formatter are correct).

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

data = []
with open('data.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        temp = line.replace(',',' ').strip('\n').split(' ')
        data.append(temp)

df = pd.DataFrame.from_records(data)
df.columns = ['date', 'time', 'temperature', 'humidity']
# if the data is not recogniced as float
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='ignore')
# you could use mean max median etc
df.humidity.mean()
```